# loop from 0x0000 to 0xfff in java

Tags: java

I want to create a loop to increment a hex value starting from `0x0000` and ending with `0xffff`.
like this:
0x0000
0x0001
0x0002
0x0003
.
.
. etc

I get them in the form of decimal number but i want it in hex form.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int i,j;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    for(i=0xA;i<=0xf;i++){
        j++;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it might be worth pointing out that unless you need both `i` and `j`, it would probably make more sense to just output the value of `i` on every iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`Integer.toHexString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use hex constants to express `int` values, and you can render `int` as hex:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 0xffff; i++)
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf( "0x%04x", j);
```

"0x" prefix is printed as-is.

"%04x" placeholder formats the integer value as a hexadecimal ('x' is hex conversion) of length 4 with leading zeros ('04' part in the placeholder).

There is also static `String.format()` method that allows to perform the same formatting without printing it immediately.

The `java.util.Formatter` class is the implementation behind this formatting methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer doesn't have any "forms" for integral/ordinal values, they are all stored and handled as a bunch of 0 and 1.

What you mean by form I think is basicly the **representation**, in this case: *Hexadecimal*.
The formated print might be what you are looking for. It let's you decide, in what format the numbers should be displayed:

```
for (i = 0x0000; i <= 0xffff; i++) {
    System.out.printf("0x%04X\n", i);
}
```

% = starts the expression
0 = zero filled infront of the actual number
4 = number of digits
X = hexdacemial, uppercase. (x would be lower case)

For further information on this very powerfull function see: [Oracle Docs - printf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)